# How is this solution linked together?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded a VS2013 library + tools solution consisting of many, many projects. When I checked the "Additional Dependencies" and "Additional Include Directories" in the projects, the manual entry fields were empty yet, they had all the necessary things in the inherited values list. What I don't understand is why or how this is done, the only editable thing I saw in relation to each other was some ticked boxes in solution -> project dependencies tab, yet when I tick some of them boxes for my own project, nothing happens as far as I can tell.

What is this sorcery??

Comment: There are property sheets also to achieve this task

Comment: The code possibly has relative #include paths and #import or #pragma comment lines in it which don't need additional dependencies..

Comment: there are no comment lines of that nature as far as I can tell, I'm looking into property sheets as soon as I can figure out what they are.

Comment: oh oh! I found them. Neat way to tie a big solution together I guess, just wish I could copy/paste the items.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they're project references (check the "references" tab in the project properties). Incidentally, this is the preferred way to have inter-project dependencies in VS. Manually adding the .lib name to "additional dependencies" works, but not as well: it interferes with incremental linking, and requires you to maintain the linker settings and project build order separately.

Comment: Common Properties -> References is empty :|

Comment: In that case, it's probably property sheets, as Pankaj mentioned.